# Unable to send a POST Request using Power Query in Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I need to send a POST request to generate an access token in Power Query. In Power BI Desktop, a POST request is sent, and it works as expected. However, when I try to refresh after publishing the report to Power BI Service, a GET request is sent instead, resulting in a "Method Not Allowed" error, and a response code of 405.

This is the error I have encountered.

[image]

This is the Power Query code I’m using

```
let
base_url = [base_url],
client_secret = [client_secret],
Source  = Json.Document(Web.Contents(base_url&"/oauth/issueToken",
    [ 
      Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json"],
      Content=Json.FromValue([
        grant_type = "client_credentials",
        client_id = "powerbi_client",
        client_secret = client_secret
      ])
    ]
)),

token = Source[access_token],
```

I'm uncertain if the problem lies with the headers and content we are using. However, I was able to send the request successfully via Postman by setting the "Content-Type" to "application/json". What’s the issue here? Any issue with my script?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might be that the `url` argument of `Web.Contents` is calculated. IIRC this is problematic authentication-wise when the report is published to Power BI service.

I would try the following to test this hypothesis: Change the `url` argument of `Web.Contents` to a static string and see if that solves the problem.